# Global click event blocks element's click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**This should happen**
If the user clicks on one of the two input boxes, the default value should be removed. When the user clicks elswhere on the webpage and one text field is empty, it should be filled with the default value from the `data-default` attribute of the spefic element.

**This happens**
When somebody clicks somewhere on the page and the field is empty, the field will be filled with the right value, but when somebody clicks in the field again the text isn't removed. It seems like the `$(document)` click event is blocking the `$(".login-input")` click event, because the `$(".login-input")` is working without the `$(document)` click event.

**JSFiddle**
A sample of my problem is provieded here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLQW9/2/)

**Tank you for helping!**

Comment: Why not use HTML5 placeholder? http://jsfiddle.net/M5nkx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not at all how you solve placeholders, you do it like so :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".login-input").on({
        focus: function () {
            if (this.value == $(this).data('default')) this.value = '';
        },
        blur: function() {
            if (this.value == '') this.value = $(this).data('default');
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kLQW9/6/)

Preferably you'd use the HTML5 placeholder attribute if really old browsers aren't an issue.

**EDIT:**

if you decide to do both, check support for placeholders in the browser before applying the javascript :

```
var i = document.createElement('input'),
hasPlaceholders = 'placeholder' in i;

if (!hasPlaceholders) {
    // place the code above here, the condition will 
    // fail if placeholders aren't supported
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats the bette solution! I will take the HTML5 placeholders, hadn't thought about them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the input, the script is working, but since the input is in the document, a click on the input is a click on the document aswell. Both function will rune, document is the last one.

That is called event bubblingand you need to stop propagation :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".login-input").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        $(this).val("");
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kLQW9/3/

Comment: What if the user types something in the input ?

Comment: You're right, this would have to be checked too, but I will take the HTML5 placeholder attribute anyway. Thank you!

Comment: @Kimmax since you already have a javascript solution, you should keep it for browser compatibility (but priorise placeholder) but yeah adeneo answer is pretty much the best one (i was just pointing what you were doing wrong).

Comment: Yes, I accepted his answer.  I'will keep the code for compatibility, so there's a solution for everyone. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".login-input").click(function () {
        $(this).val("");

    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".login-input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $(this).val($(this).attr("data-default"));
        }
    });
    $(".login-input").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $(this).val($(this).attr("data-default"));
        }
    });

});
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/APBBH/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use focus and blur events?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".login-input").focus(function () {
        $(this).val("");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".login-input").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $(this).val($(this).attr("data-default"));
        }
    });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kLQW9/5/

P.S. In yours, and this code, on focus all data fro input will be cleared. If you need to clear only default text, add proper condition for that.